# num cannot be resolved to a variable in java

Tags: arrays, parameter-passing, selection-sort

I am creating program to sort the total number of hours employees work in a week in descending order. I am only having one compilation error when I try to execute my code. It says that `"num" cannot be resolved to a variable`...

The error occurs at following line:

```
sortHours(num);                //Error occurs here
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
public class WorkerHours {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] hours = {
                    {2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
                    {7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},
                    {3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
                    {9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},
                    {3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},
                    {3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},
                    {3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},
                    {6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9}};

        int[] weeklyHours = totalHours(hours);
        sortHours(num);                //Error occurs here
        displayDescSort(weeklyHours);  

      }

      public static int[] totalHours(int[][] hours){
        int[] result1 = new int[8]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++){
            int sum = 0; 

            for (int j = 0; j < hours[i].length; j++){
                sum += hours[i][j]; 
            }

            result1[i] = sum; 
        }
        return result1; 
      }

      public static void sortHours(int[] num){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++){
            int currentMax = num[i];
            int currentMaxIndex = i;  

            for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++){
                if (currentMax < num[j]){
                    currentMax = num[j];
                    currentMaxIndex = j;
                }
            }

            if (currentMaxIndex != i){
                num[currentMaxIndex] = num[i];
                num[i] = currentMax; 
            }
        }
      } 

      public static void displayDescSort(int[] weeklyHours){
        for (int i = weeklyHours.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.println("Employee" + i + ": " + weeklyHours[i] + " hours");
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: num should be weeklyHours on the line indicated

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks